# synthesizing a bash functional application operator

Tags: bash, shell

This is a bit pie-in-the-sky but I've learned not to make assumptions about the capabilities of anything, since I'm frequently amazed by hidden features buried in UNIX/Linux tools, so here goes.

I often find myself running commands where I need to locate a file on a system and then once I've eyeballed the location for sanity, I need to do something with the path.

Take this workflow, for instance:

```
$ which foo.sh
/path/to/something/foo.sh
$ vim `which foo.sh`
```

That second command takes me 1-2 entire seconds to type.  It's madness.  I do it so often it's starting to feel like boilerplate that I should be able to factor out.

What I'd love is fantasy shell magic that would let me do the following:

```
$ which foo.sh
/path/to/something/foo.sh
$ which foo.sh |! vim
```

This second case is far superior IMO.  I find it much easier to type "|! vim" after the up-arrow than I do seeking the start of the line, typing vim backtick, then seeking the end of the line and typing a final backtick.

Imagine the pipe-bang operator doing something similar to "| xargs,vim" but in a way that preserves the terminal for vim and as also something much shorter to type.  Pipe-bang is of course a syntax error in bash and it cannot be aliased, so the thing I want to do seems impossible.

Or is it?  I suspect this is a case of TMTOWTDI but I'm having a mental block.

It doesn't have to be literally pipe-bang either, but something close is the goal.

Answer (score 2):

This should also work:

which foo.sh | xargs vim

Comment: or, in zsh:

vim =foo.sh

Answer (score 1):

I do the same thing, often (usually with which to find a binary, then rpm -qf to see which package provides it)!  My route is better than what you do, but slower than what you want; I offer it as a half-way house.

```
$ which foo.sh
/path/to/something/foo.sh
$ vim `!!`
```

On most keyboards, the backtick and the 1 key are pretty close, too, so it's fairly fast to type.

Comment: *facepalm* I don't know why sticking !! inside of backticks never occured to me, especially after all of those times I've been burned putting ! inside double-quotes.  Let me try this for a day and see how I feel :)

Comment: <large grin> don't worry about it, i definitely have those lapses, too.  as a fix, i hope it works out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Give this (**v**im **p**revious)  a try:

```
$ alias vp='vim $(fc -s)'
$ which foo.sh
$ vp
```

The `fc -s` re-executes the previous command with a substitution (null in this case).

You can put the alias in your `~/.bashrc` file. I have mine in an `aliases` file which is sourced by my `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Nice find, but is unfortunately not an answer to this question.